# A question about the form of the Fredholm theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

The Fredhom theorem is about the equation

$$ y = x - A x .$$

Why is it not about the equation

$$y = A x$$

as in the finite linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind this is to study invertible operators plus small perturbations.

If $A$ is an operator with $\|A\|<1$ then $I-A$ is invertible, since
the Neumann series
$$
(I-A)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k
$$
is converging.

The same holds, if $A$ is nilpotent, i.e. $A^l=0$ for some $l$.

If $A$ is compact then the perturbed operator $I-A$ still has some nice properties. That is, $A$ is some kind of 'small' perturbation of the invertible operator $I$.

Answer (score 0):

The operator $A$ is probably compact. That makes the operator $I-A$ Fredholm.